# Function that acts like a decorator, but uses mutation instead of wrapping?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

A decorator adds additional functionality to an object by "wrapping" around the original value.

**Is there a name for an object or function that ingests a pre-constructed object and adds additional functionality to it via mutation?**.

Example:

```
function mutatesObjects(target) {
  target.additionalFunctionality = "I've been mutated!";
}
```

This is similar to a contrcutor or factory except that it is **adding functionality to an object that was already created**.

Is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: Mixin is a fine name.

Comment: Also state pattern would fit, it mainly depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the purpose for this change, [Monkey Patching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) might apply.

"A monkey patch is a way for a program to extend or modify supporting system software locally (affecting only the running instance of the program)."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `Plugin` name as a reference to jquery plugins.

But I also think this is actually an anti-pattern in most cases. This not only breaks the encapsulation (one of the main concepts in OOP), it goes even beyond it and changes object functionality.

Imagine a simple case where you do something like:

```
doSomething(object)
```

In the best case you can hope the `object` state was not changed. In the worse case you can suspect that it was mutated and it's state changed.

It's really unexpected if you get something completely different with new methods or properties.

But of course, there can be good usages (like jquery plugins).